# Vector Initializer_list

Tags: c++11

I am trying to implement a vector using my own class so I can not do the initialiser list part

```
# include <iostream>
# include <exception>
# include<initializer_list>
template <class T>
 class vector {
  public:
  T* a;
T n;
int pos, c;
vector() { a = 0; n = 0; }
vector(T n) : n(n) { a = new T[n]; }
vector(std::initializer_list <vector> l) {
    a = new T[int(sizeof(l))];
        for (int f : l)
            *(a + f) = l.begin() + f;
     }
 void push_back(T k) {
    int i = k;
    *(a + n) = k;
}
 vector& operator= (vector&& th) {
     this->a = th.a;
    th.a = nullptr; return (*this);
}
vector& operator=(vector& k)
{
    this->a = k.a;
    return(*this);
}
int  size() { return n; }
void pop_back() { *(a + n) = nullptr;
n--;
}
void resize(int c) {  
    delete a;
    n = c;
 a = new T[c];
 }
 T operator[](int pos) {
    if (pos > sizeof(a))
        std::cout << "out of range";

    else return *(a + pos);
 }
 };
 int main() {
vector<int> a(10);
vector<char>b{ 'w','b','f','g' };
getchar();
return 0;

}
```

I am just trying to use pointer offset notation to take the initializer list items into the dynamic array but I get errors VS 17 IDE

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression   
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'const _Elem *' to 'T' 
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'const _Elem' to 'int'
```

Comment: You probably want `std::initializer_list<T>` instead of `std::initializer_list<vector>`, and range-based for loops like `for (int f : l)` give you the *elements* of l, not the indexes (so pointer math won't work).  Additionally, there is no point in using pointer arithmetic at all here, unless your goal is to confuse readers.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Nimrod!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <initializer_list>
// normally people don't place a space between '#' and 'include'

template <class T>
class vector {
public:
    T* a;
    int n;
    // probably it is length the vector
    // change T to int
    int pos, c;
    vector() { 
        a = nullptr;
        // do not use '0' to instruct null pointer 
        n = 0; 
    }

    vector(int n): n(n) { a = new T[n]; }

    vector(std::initializer_list<T> l) {
        a = new T[l.size()];
        // redundant force cast from size_t to int

        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
            a[i] = l.begin()[i];
        }
        // for (int f : l) # it seems that you wrote JavaScript before?
        //     *(a + f) = l.begin() + f;
    }

    void push_back(T k) {
        // assigns "T k" to "int i"? it's confusing

        // int i = k;
        // *(a + n) = k;
    }

    // probably still many problems
    vector& operator=(vector&& th) {
        this->a = th.a;
        th.a = nullptr;
        return (*this);
    }

    vector& operator=(vector& k) {
        this->a = k.a;
        return(*this);
    }

    int size() { return n; }

    void pop_back() { *(a + n) = nullptr;
        n--;
    }

    void resize(int c) {  
        delete a;
        n = c;
        a = new T[c];
    }

    T operator[](int pos) {
        if (pos > sizeof(a))
            std::cout << "out of range";
        else return *(a + pos);
    }
 };

int main() {
    vector<int> a(10);
    vector<char>b{ 'w','b','f','g' };
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

You still need more practice. XP

1. In your context of code, template variable for `initializer_list` should be `T` rather than `int`.
2. [Range for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) with `initializer_list<T>` will fetch the values
   **in** the list. Therefore it should belong to `T`.

Comment: Thank you very much Ive realized my mistakes